# Gmail contacts do not work

Tags: gmail, contacts

Might sound silly, but can you explain me that?

I add a contact to Gmail using standard view

> contacts > click at the '+' sign and add 
>   an email contact, say john (1st) Dude (last),
>   john.dude@gmail.nonono

Close everything, open Gmail again (HTML or standard view),
start new email and type in 'To:' field the word John.

Nothing comes. I just wanna have my contacts suggested
in the 'To:' field of gmail. What is wrong?